# GMail Sends Email from .uk.net Domains to Spam

Tags: email, spam, gmail

Gmail always puts emails from domains ending with .uk.net into spam, despite SPF, DMARC, and DKIM being passed.

If we send emails from other domains, e.g. ending with .co.uk, from the same mail server they are delivered directly into the inbox.

One of the .uk.net domains has just been configured and has never sent email before, the other has been around for quite a while.

This is NOT bulk email but just day to day emails to friends and colleagues.

Is the email protection system at Google somehow misconfigured so emails from .uk.net domains always end up in the spam folder?

Can anything be done?

Here are the headers taken from GMail:

```
Delivered-To: user@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a17:906:7ad2:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id k18csp313770ejo;
        Tue, 5 Apr 2022 06:44:12 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJymaSnUTkETbBVPxPhQrxpW8oxBBQyMycUdMLQ9IyqhiUcW9Hp/FjCHB5fgQ2Izxfj1PEhL
X-Received: by 2002:a05:600c:5103:b0:38e:705c:7db1 with SMTP id o3-20020a05600c510300b0038e705c7db1mr3238238wms.8.1649166252706;
        Tue, 05 Apr 2022 06:44:12 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1649166252; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=oedP9GF+IhwwrytC3+qBe41yZK7nt24LQlH6Wb6LoKgJxfQA04LsZJ0gMCvfbX7M9y
         DlZYzK68eiCu3vwaidBkyIzBg3akkYW5rNlmpEy9583TgskOfoyRaVXxcuuSSy3Wqjzs
         B89Xp4C0HUsNE2+mDJmepGkLv1y/Tj0Y64+HWopH7D4TDDpZtCQ5swffKEc7a1K4bO8O
         Q52rIU28P2yhtQR1ANIfld/4q0f7NylKp37Tqd1lUtpIpCa7xzDqaZt8AQL/8Td6I4C8
         XmUNLVxwzdQh/H87TXk2e8BMY5SWOyftU8IdrTDQ+R6XwqkqiEYSE6B2ZhKBzcP31VYO
         cTNA==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=user-agent:message-id:subject:to:from:date:mime-version
         :dkim-signature:dkim-signature;
        bh=4jLP7cLOUsRz0kIYuxFMb6HIuWo5d7GtJwCOXt9O8Ds=;
        b=EFLTOCrHN7NDJfSL75pukCdVE/PEUps/UV0cdj+qtW56NhYg62QLc5a+M8g9fIkQhG
         IC0liZmW9uLyLTrDNCZ1Fj6XUwjIaA1eQZbKVsa+lu5XBzxQwde3KOdhX2AcE9ZDMfhX
         1Y/V3N+gBxB44kXDZdW4fKaLkwB7o+7k735jiB9gJZ1dlbf/OdehbvEGv2uMQVjutJ4Y
         HjqGTbY5EGDv/nmLSKQ2H0MzqsjVN8RcrJGonLsU3N52LtZcDh8nxWeAqjP+dqYAKPSf
         1VFSDKoEXxmgaJSH6quoNOVQTIFb3zzZE1B6rtEm7pfYFtwVRy9jEp02hr530wHrr9+B
         iGfA==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@sabre.uk.net header.s=mail header.b=pXfCVcGS;
       dkim=pass header.i=@sabre.uk.net header.s=mail header.b="Wb/Qtyp0";
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of user@sabre.uk.net designates 217.174.255.67 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=user@sabre.uk.net;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=sabre.uk.net
Return-Path: <user@sabre.uk.net>
Received: from mail.scpcomputers.co.uk (mail.scpcomputers.co.uk. [217.174.255.67])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id f17-20020adffcd1000000b002060ddcacfdsi5168733wrs.294.2022.04.05.06.44.12
        for <user@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Tue, 05 Apr 2022 06:44:12 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of user@sabre.uk.net designates 217.174.255.67 as permitted sender) client-ip=217.174.255.67;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@sabre.uk.net header.s=mail header.b=pXfCVcGS;
       dkim=pass header.i=@sabre.uk.net header.s=mail header.b="Wb/Qtyp0";
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of user@sabre.uk.net designates 217.174.255.67 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=user@sabre.uk.net;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=sabre.uk.net
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by mail.scpcomputers.co.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id 290ED31E00E0 for <user@gmail.com>; Tue,
  5 Apr 2022 14:44:12 +0100 (BST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=sabre.uk.net; s=mail; t=1649166252; bh=S1Gz7PsLQxeUFI6sLf1gOH2F5yWQZIfnrC/8RrsqA7I=; h=Date:From:To:Subject:From; b=pXfCVcGSf8zA8HfPtjih9ctvd8jkm/gUnnuBOxfzLIHdul5kHlcVCVWeirV7SA0h/
     Kg80/eE9SoiJs4u3V6Vq/AcWZ8tZ1fXpGPSavCfgkuv7FU2fn6oCLdu2QBlCYwMJue
     KEUMQYBYHFoXv+ODqYo9YDZdis3xZPmmlLN45Ctg=
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at scpcomputers.co.uk
Received: from mail.scpcomputers.co.uk ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mail.scpcomputers.co.uk [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024) with ESMTP id Mvttj2j_GSiO for <user@gmail.com>; Tue,
  5 Apr 2022 14:44:11 +0100 (BST)
Received: from mail.scpcomputers.co.uk (mail.scpcomputers.co.uk [217.174.255.67]) by mail.scpcomputers.co.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id 60F7831E00DF for <user@gmail.com>; Tue,
  5 Apr 2022 14:44:11 +0100 (BST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=sabre.uk.net; s=mail; t=1649166251; bh=S1Gz7PsLQxeUFI6sLf1gOH2F5yWQZIfnrC/8RrsqA7I=; h=Date:From:To:Subject:From; b=Wb/Qtyp0zvZzEVxWw6q+unUg8sE0w0MGMAyz51aoVg6x1n2Xagl/Rudk1JHJLsyyn
     Xd+b+0fJanyR48p8dZpt+X9f5l4bewomE6jd50aKvvHmvXL1mutc/OqYlmvxWOCL77
     nVUkf9jYe0MnHQaqKCljI5GX1JVZwOGDybKh0Snk=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=_5ef20527584f86f63f5ccb0d75f6c08b"
Date: Tue, 05 Apr 2022 14:44:11 +0100
From: user@sabre.uk.net
To: user@gmail.com
Subject: Testing Mail Flow & Trash Folder
Message-ID: <13d7c4e6f2fd0d3716d5466b91f710d5@sabre.uk.net>
X-Sender: user@sabre.uk.net
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.3.3
```

Comment: The [postmaster](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6227174) toolbox on [postmaster.google.com](http://postmaster.google.com) is intended for domain owners and may give more hints why your email gets marked as spam despite having correct DKIM/DMARC/SPF records.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the prompt reply, I've already tried that and get: No data to display at present. Please come back later.

Comment: @SteveP The only way is build over time, ask you recipient to unmark as spam for time being. I need about half year of it, to make my domain clean and kicking as usual, same as you experiencing... even .edu sometimes get into spam tbh. And you can try to use https://multirbl.valli.org/ to check your IP is on some list or have problem or not.

Comment: Hi Benyamin, thanks for taking the time to respond. The mail server has a score of 100/100 on https://senderscore.org/ . I've checked the site you suggested and no problems there either, also all good on MXToolBox.

Comment: Your `User-Agent` says that not only you are using *Roundcube*, a software with to this day a rather peculiar way of executing javascript code from incoming emails, you are using a version which has not even had the *2018 security-relevant bugfixes* applied. Recommend you verify your client maintenance policies regardless of whether Google claims to use that in their decision making.

Comment: Hi Anx, thanks for replying. It makes no difference, the same happens if I use Outlook to send to GMail. I have upgraded our version of Roundcube being used to the latest stable release.